# BigQuery Materialized view Left Join

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, geolocation, materialized-views

I know that currently materialized views don't support LEFT JOINS, so my question is if there is a way to get the same result.
I have a table with gps coordinates (mytable1) and I want to match with certain areas (polygon) created in table mytable3. mytable2 is only to add personalized information and not important for the question itself.
My code above ... changing from LEFT to INNER works in Materialized view, but I loose the points outside the areas in mytable3.
Any idea?

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW MY_TABLE
  PARTITION BY TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(date, DAY)
  CLUSTER BY node_address
  OPTIONS (enable_refresh = true)
AS (
  SELECT
    date,
    personName,
    personId,
    area,
  FROM
    MyTable1 AS Mytable1
  INNER JOIN
    MyTable2 AS Mytable2
  ON
    Mytable1.uuid = Mytable2.uuid
  LEFT JOIN
    Mytable2 AS Polygons
  ON
    ST_CONTAINS(Polygons.geoJSON, Mytable1.gps_coordinates)
  WHERE
    type = "person"
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways that come to my mind in this question. When you have window functions or joins like you said in a MV, and you absolutely have to use a MV and cant just use a normal view, the only way is to change the MV to a non-incremental one, and set proper max-staleness etc.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/materialized-views-create#non-incremental

2. Another way is to somehow use inner join without succumbing to a left join. You can try this:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW MY_TABLE
  PARTITION BY TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(date, DAY)
  CLUSTER BY node_address
  OPTIONS (enable_refresh = true)
AS (
  SELECT
    date,
    personName,
    personId,
    area
  FROM
    MyTable1 AS Mytable1
  INNER JOIN
    MyTable2 AS Mytable2
  ON
    Mytable1.uuid = Mytable2.uuid
  INNER JOIN
    Mytable3 AS Polygons
  ON
    ST_CONTAINS(Polygons.geoJSON, Mytable1.gps_coordinates)
  WHERE
    type = "person"
  
  UNION
  
  SELECT
    date,
    personName,
    personId,
    area
  FROM
    MyTable1 AS Mytable1
  INNER JOIN
    MyTable2 AS Mytable2
  ON
    Mytable1.uuid = Mytable2.uuid
  WHERE
    type = "person"
    AND NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT 1
      FROM Mytable3 AS Polygons
      WHERE ST_CONTAINS(Polygons.geoJSON, Mytable1.gps_coordinates)
    )
);
```

the first part performs the INNER JOIN with the polygons and includes only the points that are within the defined areas. The second part retrieves the points that are not within any area by using the NOT EXISTS clause.

Comment: Many thanks! I will test both solutions.
Actually the non-incremental option can solve another issue that I just thought about. The 2nd table (Mytable2) can change over time, since I have certain badges allocated to a person, but then I can reallocate them to another person.
Does the non-increment solve this? I mean, if I change mytable2 the new updates on Mytable1 will be joined with the new changes, but the previous already in Mytable 3 are kept with the "older" date. Is this correct or how can I achieve this behaviou?

Comment: @RuiBrasFernandes, Non-incremental MV in this case is about update frequency, the minimum amount you can go down to is refresh rate to 30 mins, which might not suit some applications, but it lets you have any kind of operation you want!. (There are reasons why you cant include a window function or expensive operation in a MV, imagine everytime you get an update you have to run the window function again, a lot of compute! )

Besides that, this reallocation of badges is like a transaction that disappears from one MV when it moves to another MV, is that what u meant?